# webscrape and export csv

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to webscrape and I don't know what to put for the `userdetail[].text` or if that's even what I should be using. I'm also getting

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

```py
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time as t
import random as rnd

urltoget='http://drd.ba.ttu.edu/isqs3358/hw/hw1/'
filename1 = 'exercisedata.csv'
lowval = 5
highval = 7

res=r.get(urltoget)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')

user = soup.find('div', attrs={'id':'UserIndex'})
userurls = user.find_all('a')

with open(filename1,'w') as exercisedata:
    datawriter = csv.writer(exercisedata, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',     quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    datawriter.writerow(['rank', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'avg_sleep',     'avg_water','avg_step','day', 'day_water', 'day_step', 'metric'])
    for user in userurls:
        href = user['href']
        userres = r.get(urltoget + href)
        usersoup = BeautifulSoup(userres.content, 'lxml')
        userinfo = usersoup.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'userinfo'}).find_all('span', attrs=    {'class' : 'val'})
        datawriter.writerow([href.split('=')[1]               
                        
                             ,userdetail[].text
                        
        timetosleep = rnd.randint(lowval, highval) + rnd.random()
        t.sleep(timetosleep)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Would be an improved code that works.
Important to note the ID of the div is not UserIndex instead it is UsrIndex.

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



urltoget = 'http://drd.ba.ttu.edu/isqs3358/hw/hw1/'
filename1 = 'exercisedata.csv'
lowval = 5
highval = 7

res = r.get(urltoget)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')

user = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'UsrIndex'})
print(user)
userurls = user.find_all('a')
```

Comment: it prints the data but doesn't put it into the csv file

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you want is all in HTML tables you can do this just using pandas and the "read_html" method:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://drd.ba.ttu.edu/isqs3358/hw/hw1/'
df = pd.read_html(url,extract_links='body')[0]

output = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    xdf = pd.read_html(url+row[0][1])[0]
    xdf['name'] = row['Name'][0]
    xdf['rank'] = row['Rank'][0]
    xdf['user_id'] = row[0][1].split('=')[-1]

    output.append(xdf)

fdf = pd.concat(output)
fdf.to_csv('+output.csv',index=False)
```